# How to set static width to view in SWT

Tags: java, swt

how can be configured static width of view in perspective?

I'd like have on left side TreeViewer with static width and second view (ViewPart) want to expand horizontaly. I have this, witch used ratio, that i don't want:

```
public class PerspectivaEkomaj implements IPerspectiveFactory {

    @Override
    public void createInitialLayout( IPageLayout layout ) {

        String editorArea = layout.getEditorArea();
        layout.setEditorAreaVisible( false );
        layout.addView( EkomajTreeView.RCP_ID, IPageLayout.LEFT, 0.25f, editorArea );
        layout.getViewLayout( EkomajTreeView.RCP_ID ).setCloseable( false );

        layout.addStandaloneView( MajetekView.RCP_ID, false, IPageLayout.TOP, 0.75f, editorArea );
        layout.addStandaloneViewPlaceholder( MajetekDMView.RCP_ID, IPageLayout.TOP, 0.75f, editorArea, false );
...
```

Pls let me know if exist some work around or similar class (compatible with SWT) that allow it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to control the size of a specific workbench part (view or editor), have a look at the `org.eclipse.ui.ISizeProvider` interface. If a workbench part can be adapted to `ISizeProvider`, then this is used to calculate the resulting size. See `org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPartReference.computePreferredSize(...)` for the relevant adapter code...

Comment: Thanks this seams to be good. I implements in my treeViewer class ISizeProvider interface as you sad. Thats give me two methods. getSizeFlags (I return 0) and computePreferredSize (I return exact pixel width, thats for me 300). And in perspective set floating ratio to 0.0f (static size is minimum and view expand by floating ratio if size is greater)